# Need the Audio player to supersede audio from video playing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a workout app and every exercise move is a small 3-4 second video looped over and over. Users go through their workouts by following along the moves (videos) on the screen. Now the problem. When I am playing music and I start a workout, as soon as the first move (video) starts to play, the music cuts off. This makes sense since most videos would have audio accompanying them but mine don't. I tried the following but still no luck:

```
<video muted src="whatever"></video>
```

So is there a workaround to force the audio to continue to play even when a video is playing?

App is being built on ionic framework for both iOS and Andriod.

Edit:
I placed a song inside the app on the same view as the video, it worked.

I feel the solution must be a cordova preference or plugin that allows for such functionality (i.e. preference name="" value="true")

Comment: Could you not just add an audio track to the playing video??

Comment: The audio will most likely be user's own music (ipod, spotify, pandora) or whatever else they like to listen to while working out

Comment: removing the audio from the video files should stop the tab sound management (no audio icon or bg mute)

Comment: When I exported I the videos from premiere pro I unchecked the audio box. Other than that,  how would I go about removing the audio files?

Comment: You could allow your user to select audio tracks from their device and play them in an audio element. But that wouldn't stop spotify etc closing...